# Open image with PIL Image.open() from another directory

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to open an image using the `pillow` library (Image.open). The image is located in a different directory to the script that is running. If I use `os.chdir()` to the directory where the file is located it works fine but that breaks other parts of the system.

The function below is below an image for a web uploader (the software is always offline because it is used in a field somewhere)

The path variable and is the `path/to/file`
The filename variable is just the filename

So the question is, how do I open the file when it's located in a separate directory.

```
def convert(self, path, filename):
    # os.chdir(path)
    file_loc = os.path.join(path, filename)
    im = Image.open(file_loc)
    s = float(os.path.getsize(filename)) / float(1024*1024)
    reduced_size = self.image_width, self.image_height
    im = im.resize(reduced_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    watermarked = self.watermark(im)
    im.save(filename, "JPEG", quality=75, optimise=True, progressive=True, watermark=watermarked)   
    im.thumbnail((200, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return True
```

Things I've already tried:

1. with `Image.open(open(file_loc, 'rb')`
2. `Image.open(r""+file_loc)`
3. `path = os.path.dirname(__file__)`
   `os.path.join(path, filename)`

Comment: first you could use `print( file_loc )` to check if you created correct path. And then you can copy this path and check if you can access it in console or if you can open it with other program. Maybe you created wrong path and now it can't find it.

Comment: do you get error message ? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: are you sure you have problem in `Image.open()` ? You use filename without path in `getsize(filename)` but it also need `file_loc`. And the same problem you can have with `save(filename)` - if you want to save in the same place then you should use `save(file_loc)`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I checked that the path is correct. I've fixed it now with glob (solution below). Thanks for your input

Comment: it is strange for me that it works with `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, filename))` because it returns `list` with filename instead of single `filename`.  It can be useful also when you have folder name instead of file name - and it would means that your `filename` wasn't filename but folder name - so you simply used wrong value in code.

Comment: @furas yes you're right, that would throw an error but then I just opened the image with Image.open(path[0]) and it works fine.

Comment: did you check what you have in `path`? What did you have in `filename`? For me It looks like you used wrong values in `filename` - folder name instead of filename or ie. `*.jpg` - so all your problem was in different place - in incorrect data.

Comment: @furas all of the variables are correct. The issue was because Image.open() was trying to open the image in the same directory as the script that was being run. I just needed a way to point that function to where the file actually is. It works now, thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with glob to access the image from a different directory:

```
import glob

path = glob.glob("C/Images/)

def convert(self, path, filename):
    # taking the path from glob 
    im = Image.open(file_loc)
    s = float(os.path.getsize(filename)) / float(1024*1024)
    reduced_size = self.image_width, self.image_height
    im = im.resize(reduced_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    watermarked = self.watermark(im)
    im.save(filename, "JPEG", quality=75, optimise=True, progressive=True, watermark=watermarked)   
    im.thumbnail((200, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return True
```

Comment: I tried it with glob.glob(path) and it doesn't work. The path changes everytime the function is run.

Comment: I've fixed it, thank you. a small adjustment to your suggestion and it worked. path = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, filename)). Thank you